# what is the "Drag" and how did it come about?

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have define a custom actions in my accessibilityElement:

```
UIAccessibilityCustomAction *action1 = ...initWithName:@"label1";
UIAccessibilityCustomAction *action2 = ...initWithName:@"label2";
element.accessibilityCustomActions = @[action1, action2];
```

When swipe down/up, it reads "Drag" in addition to the normal "label1", "label2", what is this "Drag" and how did it come about?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that comes along and sees this, I was having the same issue, and I was able to find that Apple added (sometime around iOS 11) the [UITextDraggable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextdraggable) protocol to UITextView.

This is defined as:

> The interface that determines if a text view is a drag source.

This protocol has the property `textDragInteraction` that defaults to true for UITextViews.

You can set this property to false like this:

Swift:

```
textView.textDragInteraction?.isEnabled = false
```

Obj-C:

```
textView.textDragInteraction.enabled = NO;
```